# What is the Powershell equivalent of "Use the following IP Address" in the IPv4 properties UI?

Tags: windows, azure, powershell

I am looking for a Powershell command that disables DHCP and sets the machine's private IP as a static IP; basically, I'm looking for the Powershell equivalent of following actions in the UI.

Control panel -> Network and Sharing Center -> Ethernet -> Properties -> IPv4 -> Properties -> toggle off "Obtain an IP address automatically" and toggle on "Use the following IP address" -> fill out IPv4 address, default gateway, and subnet mask.

[image: I want to Powershell this window]

The following commands, taken from [this guide](https://www.pdq.com/blog/using-powershell-to-set-static-and-dhcp-ip-addresses-part-1/), seems to describe what I'm after, but `Remove-NetIPAddress` results in kicking me off the server and locking me out.

```
$IP = "10.10.10.10"
$MaskBits = 24 # This means subnet mask = 255.255.255.0
$Gateway = "10.10.10.1"
$Dns = "10.10.10.100"
$IPType = "IPv4"
# Retrieve the network adapter that you want to configure
$adapter = Get-NetAdapter | ? {$_.Status -eq "up"}
# Remove any existing IP, gateway from our ipv4 adapter
If (($adapter | Get-NetIPConfiguration).IPv4Address.IPAddress) {
 $adapter | Remove-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily $IPType -Confirm:$false
}
If (($adapter | Get-NetIPConfiguration).Ipv4DefaultGateway) {
 $adapter | Remove-NetRoute -AddressFamily $IPType -Confirm:$false
}
 # Configure the IP address and default gateway
$adapter | New-NetIPAddress `
 -AddressFamily $IPType `
 -IPAddress $IP `
 -PrefixLength $MaskBits `
 -DefaultGateway $Gateway
```

I'm unable to create a new IPv4 address so long as the existing one is still around, but removing the existing one borks the connection to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is incorrect. You can set multiple IPs on the same interface. So you simply add the new one with `New-NetIPAddress` and then remove the previous one.

[image]

```
$currentIP = Get-NetIPAddress | where ipaddress -eq '192.168.43.96'

New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias $currentIP.InterfaceAlias -IPAddress 192.168.43.20 -PrefixLength 24

Remove-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias $currentIP.InterfaceAlias -IPAddress $currentIP.IPAddress
```

[image]

The DNS and Gateway are separate things. Just don't change those if you don't need to. To avoid the confirmation prompt, simply add `-Confirm:$false` to the `Remove-NetIPAddress` command.

Comment: This answer is incomplete/incorrect because you are not setting the original IP